# How do I separate inline images and attaches using MAPI?

Tags: windows, email, outlook, mapi

My program uses MAPI for working with Exchange mailboxes. The problem is if a user fires up Outlook, adds a file as an attachment and also opens Paint, selects a region there, copies it into clipboard and pastes into the message body the resulting message showns two attachments.

More specifically, the program calls `IMAPIMessage::GetAttachmentsTable()` to retrieve the attachments table and that table contains two objects. Is there a way a program can decide whether the "attachment" is really an attached file or a portion of inline content?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check whether the HTML body (through the img tag) refers to the attachment, either through img:cid and PT_ATTACH_CONENTS_ID property or though the file name (PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME) or contnet location (PR_ATTACH_COMTENT_LOCATION).

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to look for `PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN`. If it's set then it's an inline image and doesn't appear as a regular attachment when viewing the email.

Answer (score -1):

The property you are looking for is PR_RENDERING_POSITION (0x370B0003).  A -1 means that the attachment is a "normal" attachment and not in-line.  If the value is anything other than -1, then that indicates an in-line attachment and the value is the position in the body that the attachment should be rendered at.

Here is the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842381%28office.12%29.aspx) describing it.

---

EDIT:

Dmitry, I do not agree with your comment.  I have HTML email messages with in-line attachments and the PR_RENDERING_POSITION is working as described in the MSDN page I posted.

Comment: No, PR_RENDERING_POSITION  is only appliable to the RTF messages.
It is always -1 for the HTML and text messages.

Comment: Could you post a reference to this?  MSDN says the opposite, and I have HTML email examples do not agree with you examined using Outlook Spy.

Comment: The MSDN page does not mention HTML at all.
You can change that property using OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI, it won't make any difference for the HTML or TXT messages.

Comment: I'd be curious to look at a message like that. Are you sure you are not looking at an RTF message?
HTML messages refer to embedded images using the <img> tag, there is no absolute (character wise) image positioning in HTML.